# Java split Arraylist into smaller ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with a size of `258`

Now i wish to split this into three different ArrayLists for this i have created the following code:

```
    Integer start = (int) Math.floor((sitesToSearch.size() / 3));
    Integer middle = (int) Math.floor((sitesToSearch.size() / 2));
    Integer end = (int) Math.floor((sitesToSearch.size() / 1));

    ArrayList<String> crawl_list1 = (ArrayList<String>)tmp.subList(0, start);
    ArrayList<String> crawl_list2 = (ArrayList<String>)tmp.subList(start+1, middle);
    ArrayList<String> crawl_list3 = (ArrayList<String>)tmp.subList(middle+1, end);
```

Sadly this throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList$SubList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

So how can i devide it into three smaller ArrayList

```
tmp declaration:

public ArrayList<String> getExternalLinks(ArrayList<String> rootDomains){
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

Document doc = null;
/*
 * Check if root is valid
 * Find search the site for internal links
 */
for (String root : rootDomains) {
    if (!(root == null) || !root.isEmpty() ||!root.contains("#")) {
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(root)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .get();
            result.addAll(findExternalLinks(findInternalLinks(doc,root),root)); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(result.size());
return result;
```

}

Comment: How do you define tmp? and how it is populated?

Comment: Can you please show the decleration of `tmp`

Comment: What is the relation between `sitesToSearch` and `tmp`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [casting Arrays.asList causing exception: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641006/casting-arrays-aslist-causing-exception-java-util-arraysarraylist-cannot-be-ca)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use `List<String>` as the type of `crawl_list1`.

That's just an application of the general rule of ["code against the interface"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

There's really no good reason to require the return value of `subList` to be an `ArrayList` (and it doesn't make sense as `subList` returns a *view* onto the original `ArrayList`).

If you *absolutely* need `ArrayList` objects, then you need to copy the content into *new* `ArrayList` objects:

```
ArrayList<String> crawl_list1 = new ArrayList<String>(tmp.subList(0, start));
ArrayList<String> crawl_list2 = new ArrayList<String>(tmp.subList(start+1, middle));
ArrayList<String> crawl_list3 = new ArrayList<String>(tmp.subList(middle+1, end));
```

Comment: i need to split it into three Arraylists because i have to iterate over each of the three lists

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: so? you can iterate over a `List` just as easily as over an `ArrayList`.

Comment: i can't do foreach can i?

Comment: Yes, you should code to interfaces as much as possible: Use `List` everywhere that a method returns the `List`. Only use `ArrayList` when you need to instantiate a new one yourself.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: Haven't I just said that you can do exactly that? Have you tried it? You can use foreach with every `Iterable` (which includes `Collection` which includes `List`).

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: you should be able to replace every `ArrayList` in your code simply with `List` (except where you do `new ArrayList()`).

Comment: @JoachimSauer oh yeah i can :D lol had the wrong import! what did you mean about the excluded thing?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: you can't do `new List()` because `List` is an interface. That's the only place where you still need to use `new ArrayList()` even if you code against the interface. In all other places, you should simply use `List` instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) for `ArrayList.subList()`. It doesn't return an `ArrayList`. It returns a `List`. There's no reason to cast this list to an ArrayList. It's a list, and that's all you need to know:

```
List<String> crawl_list1 = tmp.subList(0, start);
List<String> crawl_list2 = tmp.subList(start+1, middle);
List<String> crawl_list3 = tmp.subList(middle+1, end);
```

Also, you should check your indices, because the end index passed to subList is exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

.subList(fromIndex, toIndex) is inclusive for fromIndex and exclusive for toIndex. With the current code middle and start will never populate an ArrayList.

The below two are assumptions of the logic:

.subList(start, middle)

.subList(middle, end+1)

Comment: "exclusive for toIndex". that is really good to know. Probably should have read the documentation on that one :p