# How to convert List<CustomClass> to ArrayList<CustomClass> and vise-versa?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have a `CustomClass` which is `Bean/Model/Pojo` and it is used to save Custom Obejcts from Json. I want to save the `ArrayList` of my `CustomClass` in `SharedPreference` and retrieve it back in a special scenario. I found a way of storing it in `SharedPreference` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981233/android-arraylist-of-custom-objects-save-to-sharedpreferences-serializable)! The correct answer is working by `SpyZip`
I am able to store and retrieve a `List` but I want to store and retrieve an `ArrayList` instead.

Here is a snippet showing how I store and retrieve value in `SharedPreference`:

```
    // This method will save custom class ArrayList<Bean>
    public void saveUserFavouriteStations(
            ArrayList<RadioStationBean> radioStation) {
        FavouriteStationHolder = this.getSharedPreferences("stations", 0);
        Editor editor = FavouriteStationHolder.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonCars = gson.toJson(radioStation);
        editor.putString("stations", jsonCars);
        System.out.println("Custom ArrayList Saved in App Class");
        editor.commit();
    }

    public ArrayList<RadioStationBean> getUserFavouriteStations() {
        FavouriteStationHolder = this.getSharedPreferences("stations", 0);
        if (FavouriteStationHolder != null) {
            String jsonString = FavouriteStationHolder
                    .getString("stations", "");
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<RadioStationBean>>() {
            }.getType();
            List<RadioStationBean> carsList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
            return carsList;
        } else {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ArrayList<RadioStationBean> carsList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type); how about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [casting Arrays.asList causing exception: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641006/casting-arrays-aslist-causing-exception-java-util-arraysarraylist-cannot-be-ca)

Comment: why you are creating un-useful object just return `return gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);`

Comment: @dnozay Not the duplicate, if you read the question clearly

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, if you read my question carefully, i want to return ArrayList<CustomClass> , not the gson response

Comment: @diva, if i wont get a solution, i will try it, thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sad but none solutions worked, A `List<CustomClass>` can not be casted directly to `ArrayList<CustomClass>` so, i tried to make my own solution by parsing the json i get from gson by making a new CustomClass object and using a `for` iterator to construct a new ArrayList using following code

```
if (FavouriteStationHolder != null) {
            String jsonString = FavouriteStationHolder
                    .getString("stations", "");
            System.out.println("json String got in App class-->" + jsonString);

            Type type = new TypeToken<List<RadioStationBean>>() {
            }.getType();
            List<RadioStationBean> stations = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
            ArrayList<RadioStationBean> stationsList = new ArrayList<RadioStationBean>();
            for (int i = 0; i < stations.size(); i++) {
                RadioStationBean rBean = new RadioStationBean();
                rBean.setAdvertisements(stations.get(i).getAdvertisements());
                rBean.setCategories_id(stations.get(i).getCategories_id());
                rBean.setCategoy(stations.get(i).getCategoy());
                rBean.setDescription(stations.get(i).getDescription());
                rBean.setFacebook(stations.get(i).getFacebook());
                rBean.setId(stations.get(i).getId());
                rBean.setImage_url(stations.get(i).getImage_url());
                rBean.setIsDispTrack_Artist(stations.get(i)
                        .getIsDispTrack_Artist());
                rBean.setManager_detail(stations.get(i).getManager_detail());
                rBean.setPhone_show(stations.get(i).getPhone_show());
                rBean.setPhone_studio(stations.get(i).getPhone_studio());
                rBean.setPhone_toll_free(stations.get(i).getPhone_toll_free());
                rBean.setPlatform(stations.get(i).getPlatform());
                rBean.setStation_image(stations.get(i).getStation_image());
                rBean.setStation_manager(stations.get(i).getStation_manager());
                rBean.setStation_manager_id(stations.get(i)
                        .getStation_manager_id());
                rBean.setStation_name(stations.get(i).getStation_name());
                rBean.setStation_status(stations.get(i).getStation_status());
                rBean.setStream_format(stations.get(i).getStream_format());
                rBean.setStream_url(stations.get(i).getStream_url());
                rBean.setTheme_color(stations.get(i).getTheme_color());
                rBean.setTwitter(stations.get(i).getTwitter());
                rBean.setWeb_portal(stations.get(i).getWeb_portal());
                stationsList.add(rBean);
            }
            System.out.println("Custom ArrayList Retrieved in App Class"
                    + stationsList.get(0).getDescription());

            return stationsList;
}
```

Thanks a lot to all for making efforts to help me and kick off to Downvoter and Duplicators

Answer (score 6):

[`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a specific (array based) implementation of the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface. Since you should only rarely care about the underlying implementation, and this doesn't seem to be one of those rare cases, just change your method signatures to use `List` in both the argument list and the return value.

Answer (score 1):

You simply converting java object to string and store this string in SharedPreferences and While retrieving data you are converting this String back to java Object. use Type ArrayList to get data in ArrayList.

```
  String jsonString = FavouriteStationHolder
                .getString("stations", "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<RadioStationBean>>() {
        }.getType();
        ArrayList<RadioStationBean> carsList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Comment: NullPointer, however i am able to print jsonString, data is correct, the only problem is in converting list

Comment: I mean use ArrayList while saving and retrieving. is this worked?